# Как из контейнера обратиться в терминал другого контейнера

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci

У нас есть автотесты на cypress. Раньше мы на виртуалке запускали все сервисы вместе с приложением и тесты выполняли снаружи ВМ, то есть на локалке, поэтому перед каждым тестом реализовано рефрешь БД и сид , только определенных для данного теста таблиц, определенными данными. Реализовано это следующим образом, cypress стучиться по ssh в виртуалку приложения и в консоли приложения выполняет различные команды по сиду БД, каждый раз команды чуть чуть разные. Теперь поставили задачу запустить все это в gitlab-ci, собственно я так понимаю что там через докер композ будет подниматься 3 контейнера:

1. с постгрессом
2. с приложением
3. с сайпрессом, теперь ввиду изменений, как мне реализовать функционал что бы cypress как и ранее мог стучаться в контейнер с приложением, что бы в контейнере с приложением выполнялись определенные команды для сида БД? Сидить перед тестами всю БД всеми данными долговато и проблематично для тестов, хотелось бы попытаться оставить старую логику (сайпресс сам в нужный момент выполняет нужные команды в терминале приложения)

Comment: Зачем вам сидить БД? Сделайте несколько имиджей каждый со своей предустановленной базой. Для запуска теста создаёте контейнер из подходящего имиджа с уже готовой минимальной базой. Для приложения в образ добавьте sshd и настройки .ssh/config для тестового пользователя, прокиньте 22-й порт.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у нас в компании все на ci-template, вряд ли мне дадут добавить sshd в контейнеры, в принципе сколько не искал, простых вариантов нет, либо писать апи для сида, либо sshd, либо устанавливать dind, либо прокидывать docker.sock, надеялся что есть золотая пуля.